# effect of size of the hash table on access speed

Tags: hashtable

I read about this question in an interview forum & I am not sure about the answer. Please help me out. Is it better to have multiple small hash tables or one big hash table in terms of access speed (assuming both fit in RAM)? I think the answer should be; both give same performance as the access time would be same. But I am confused about multiple small hash tables.

Comment: I would note that splitting the data into mahy small hashtables must be hidden behind an interface of "ordinary", single hashtable. Polluting application logic so much for questionable (and anyway not very impressive) performance benefits is WTF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such a question depends on a lot of factors, such as the implementation of the hash function and how you choose which table.

In general, if both fit in memory, the speed should be comparable.  A hash table takes a key, converts it to a number, and looks up the value.  With multiple small tables, you have to choose which hash table, so that adds an extra layer.  On the other hand, modern computer architectures have multiple levels of caching in RAM, so a small hash table might be in a cache, making accesses quicker.